# SSIS Multiple Table Inserts vs. Union ALL

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS and I am writing my first SSIS package.

In my package, in the data flow there are several stages of transformation and for each stage a script component is inserting records (some sort of custom Log) to a ADO.NET destination.

I am using multiple ADO.NET Destination component that is pointing to the same table in the same database.

I wonder if this is a correct approach or if I should use Union ALL and insert all records at once.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: question doesn't make sense....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance perspective you would like get a very very small performance increase if you UNION the results together in SSIS and them insert them into the database in one chuck, because you will only be creating one connection to the instance/database and depending on when the dirty pages are written to disc it is possible but by no means garunteed that the head may need to move over the spindle fewer times.

What I think is a much higher importance here is what is the custom logging for? If the logging is recording how far through the package you are, how many records have been updated at a certain stage, etc then I would strongly advise against UNION in package at insert them all at the end for the following reason.

Imagine a scenario when the package falls over half way through and you are tasked with first diagnosing the issue and secondly fixing up some data that is corrupt as a result of the failure . If you write all the log entries at the end, and the package has not completed, the log entries will not be written and your task will be much harder.

Instead, I would set the ADO connection manager to retain same connection. This way, the connection will stay open for the whole time and you will not have the overhead of having to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I think Union All and then insert all at once is better.

it will make your ssis clear and get a better performance. (as I known, SSIS will use server resource instead of database resource, right?)

Comment: "SSIS will use server resource instead of database resource" - what does that mean?

Comment: For example, you are runing SSIS in Server-S, all the union jobs will use Server-S's resource.